# Type Conversion in Python using ord()

Tags: python-3.x

```
s = '4'
c = ord(s)
print ("After converting character to integer : ",end="")
print (c)
```

output: After converting character to integer : 52

I don't understand the value of output. Can someone please explain why 52 is printed?

Answer (score 1):

If you want become a string into integer you need use the **int() function**, ord() function returns an integer representing Unicode code point for the given Unicode character.

Example

```
s = '4'
c = int(s)
print ("After converting character to integer : ",end="")
print (c)
```

Comment: Still unable to understand. '4' is a character and ord() is used to convert character to integer. So how '4'(character) is converted to 52 (integer)

Comment: There is a table called UNICODE where there are equivalents between characters with their respective "real" numbers for example the character 'A' is really a number that is 41, in the past years existed other table called ASCII table but it supports until 255 characters like letters, numbers etc. and only in English language but in the programming was necessary to support other idioms like Chinese, Japanese then  Unicode table came to solve this problem. https://unicode-table.com/en/

Comment: Now I have understood. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Python’s built-in function chr() is used for converting an Integer to a Character, while the function ord() is used to do the reverse, i.e, convert a Character to an Integer.

For example :

```
print([(chr(i),i) for i in range(49, 123)])
```

output is :

> [('1', 49), ('2', 50), ('3', 51), ('4', 52), ('5', 53), ('6', 54), ('7', 55), ('8', 56), ('9', 57), (':', 58), (';', 59), ('<', 60), ('=', 61), ('>', 62), ('?', 63), ('@', 64), ('A', 65), ('B', 66), ('C', 67), ('D', 68), ('E', 69), ('F', 70), ('G', 71), ('H', 72), ('I', 73), ('J', 74), ('K', 75), ('L', 76), ('M', 77), ('N', 78), ('O', 79), ('P', 80), ('Q', 81), ('R', 82), ('S', 83), ('T', 84), ('U', 85), ('V', 86), ('W', 87), ('X', 88), ('Y', 89), ('Z', 90), ('[', 91), ('\', 92), (']', 93), ('^', 94), ('_', 95), ('`', 96), ('a', 97), ('b', 98), ('c', 99), ('d', 100), ('e', 101), ('f', 102), ('g', 103), ('h', 104), ('i', 105), ('j', 106), ('k', 107), ('l', 108), ('m', 109), ('n', 110), ('o', 111), ('p', 112), ('q', 113), ('r', 114), ('s', 115), ('t', 116), ('u', 117), ('v', 118), ('w', 119), ('x', 120), ('y', 121), ('z', 122)]

The ord() function takes a string argument of a single Unicode character and returns its integer Unicode code point value. It does the reverse of chr().